# With WCF WsdlExporter how to create a WSDL exactly like singleWsdl?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

When I create a WCF Service Application, I get a simple service with two methods. If I run it, I get a page on which I can click on the singleWsdl page. The WSDL is over 100 lines long and it works in SoapUI and WcfTestClient.

Now I want to create that exact same WSDL using WslExporter. (See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlexporter?view=netframework-4.8)

My attempt:

```c#
WsdlExporter exporter = new WsdlExporter();
exporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
var myContract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IService1));
exporter.ExportContract(myContract);
exporter.ExportEndpoint(
    new ServiceEndpoint(myContract, new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://x.y.z/Service1.svc")));

string wsdl;
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    exporter.GeneratedWsdlDocuments[0].Write(sw);
    wsdl = sw.ToString();
}
return wsdl;
```

But the result is a WSDL with far less lines. If loaded in SoapUI of WcfTestClient it produces errors. So... how can I create a WSDL which does work?

*** **EDIT** ***

In Visual Studio 2017 I created a new project: WCF Service Application
Part of this empty project is the next class, which is used in the contract:

```c#
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

If I start it up, I get the this WSDL:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Turien.Dynamic.Basic"/>
            <xs:element name="GetData">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GetDataResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GetDataResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Turien.Dynamic.Basic" minOccurs="0" name="composite" nillable="true" type="q1:CompositeType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GetDataUsingDataContractResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Turien.Dynamic.Basic" minOccurs="0" name="GetDataUsingDataContractResult" nillable="true" type="q2:CompositeType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
            <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
            <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
            <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
            <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="char">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="duration">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
                    <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
                    <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="guid">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Turien.Dynamic.Basic" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Turien.Dynamic.Basic">
            <xs:complexType name="CompositeType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BoolValue" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StringValue" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="CompositeType" nillable="true" type="tns:CompositeType"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContractResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IService1">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Service1">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/Turien.Dynamic.Basic/Service1.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

With my code to extract the WSDL I get this:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="service" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Turien.Dynamic.Basic"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetData"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetData_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDataUsingDataContractResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IService1">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
            <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" message="tns:IService1_GetData_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetData_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
            <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService1_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetData">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="service">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/Turien.Dynamic.Basic/Service.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As you can see the complex type / class `CompositeType` with properties `BoolValue` and `StringValue` are missing.

Comment: Right now I work with a workaround. That was enough for my POC. I will try your answer again next friday.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the metadataSet first:

```
        var exporter2 = new WsdlExporter();
        exporter2.ExportEndpoint(myServiceEndpoints[0]);
        var metadataSet = exporter.GetGeneratedMetadata();
        var schemaStream = new MemoryStream();
        metadataSet.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(new StreamWriter(schemaStream)));
        schemaStream.Position = 0;
        var source = XDocument.Load(
            new XmlTextReader(schemaStream));

        Console.WriteLine(source);
```

After getting the metadataSet, we need to intercept its content, because SOAPUI cannot recognize **MetadataSection**, we only need to extract the content in the middle of **wsdl:definitions**.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

**wsdl:definitions** contains endpoint information:

[image]

I’m not sure what happened on your side, but it’s feasible on my side. I saved the **source** into a txt file and deleted the unnecessary nodes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The part you selected looks exactly the same as the 38 lines I started with. So I am sorry, no progress there... :/

Comment: The "wsdl:definitions" I got according to your method is really useless, it is a bit similar to what I got before but not the same. The "wsdl:definitions" obtained according to your method has no endpoint information may be caused by this reason, you can try to use My code.

Comment: I did try it, it did not work. SoapUI and WcfTestClient gave an error.

Comment: I updat my reply.

Comment: I tried again with a total clean new project. I updated my question with that information. You are right... loading the WDL-file with SoapUI does not produce an error. But it also does not produce a correct client-interface. I am missing (in my example) the the class `CompositeType` with properties BoolValue and StringValue. The complex types are completely missing / empty. Your example produces the same incomplete WSDL as mine.